# Distribution function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> We have random variables $X(a)=$ $\mathbb x^{2}$y and $Y(a)=$$\mathbb x^{2}$+$\mathbb y^{2}$ where '$a$' is a point $(x,y)$ chosen at random uniformly from the unit square $[0, 1]$ $X$ $[0 1]$. In each case find the formula for, and show a plot of, the distribution functions of the random variables $X$ and $Y$

What does it mean to find a formula for distribution function?
What does $X(a)=$$\mathbb x^{2}$y  mean here?

Comment: The formula for the distribution function means the _probability density function_ (pdf).

Comment: How do I approach this problem

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: why does *distribution function* not mean *cumulative distribution function*?

Comment: @Henry I actually think it means cdf and not pdf here.

Comment: What does X(a)= $\mathbb x^{2}$y mean here. Is it not a distribution function of random variable? If not what is it?

Comment: @rowang - For some a you choose a pair of random values for x and y. You then preform the function X or the function Y. The first is $x^2y$. So for a = (x,y) = (0.5, 0.1) then $X(0.5,0.1) = 0.25^2*0.1 = 0.00625 $ Given a large sample of the values what if the PDF curve going to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$x$ and $y$ are in effect random variables, independently uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, so $$\displaystyle P(X \le c) = P(x^2y \le c) = \int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{\min(1,c/x^2)} 1 \,dy \, dx$$ 
$$\displaystyle P(Y \le c) = P(x^2+y^2 \le c) = \int_{x=0}^{\min(1,\sqrt{c})}\int_{y=0}^{\min(1,\sqrt{c-x^2})} 1 \,dy \, dx$$ 
which you can find by careful integration or by geometry.  Remember that $c$ can take any real value.

Comment: Can you give some more explanation